# Converting String to Number in Aggregation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I'm looking for a way to use Mongoose's aggregation pipeline to sum data. I have a schema that looks like this:

```
var Object = new Schema ({
    Object2 : { type : ObjectId, ref : 'Object2' },
    Object3 : { type : ObjectId, ref : 'Object3' },
    value : {},
    unit : String
})
```

The 'value' field will typically be a number, but I am allowing the user to include text in the field that transforms the number. Thus, value is stored as a string, and then I convert it into a number. I can't just store it as a number because there will be no way to convert it back for the user's display.

I've been trying to perform a Mongoose $sum pipeline to sum these values, while still allowing me to convert the number. Here is what I've tried:

```
data.aggregate([
    { $match: 
        {
            $and: [{Object2: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)}, {Object3: {$in: sessions.map(function(this){ return new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(this._id); })}}]
        }
    },
    { $project:
        {
            'value': calculateNumber('value')
        } 
    },
    { $group: 
        {
            _id: null,
            value: { $sum: "$value"},
            unit: { $first: "$unit"}
        }
    }
], function(err, result) {
    sendCallback(err, result, callback);
    return;
})
```

However, I get a value of 0. Not using the project stage gives a value of 0, and I can't figure out if there is any way to use the project stage to apply my function and convert the fields to Numbers, so that I can take advantage of $sum.

Any help, without just declaring value as a Number in my schema, would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you store it as a number and as a string? Or, better yet, store it as a number, along with another field which allows you to reverse engineer your way back to the user input.

Comment: Two big problems here 1. You are trying to pass in a function to the aggregation pipeline and it does not work like that. You can only evaluate values "before" the pipeline is sent to the server. No external functions are called by the aggregation pipeline at all. 2. There is no native function that will convert a string to a number. Convert your data as it does not make sense to store things that are clearly numeric as strings. If for some reason you cannot convert your data then use mapReduce, as JavaScript code will be able to re-cast as numeric.

Comment: Ok thanks guys, appreciate it a lot, taking your suggestions.